# excel vba to populate combobox in worksheet from sql select query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select, combobox

I have a good connection in Excel to the sqlDb (in a Module - public function).

I have used this connection with a simple Select query (in Sheet1 code) which works nicely. Per below code:

```
Private Sub Selection()

Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim sqlstr As String
sqlstr = "Select * from Selection"

Call connectDatabase
rs.Open sqlstr, DBCONT

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
          With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = rs(0)
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = rs(1)
          End With
          rs.movenext
     Next i
 Else
    MsgBox "FFS"

 End If
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Call closeDatabase

 End Sub
```

Now rather than output these results into cells (1,1) and (1,2) of Sheet1, **I want above results to populate my Combobox1 on Sheet1** and do away with the output.  I have looked at a lot of solutions but I am struggling.

Grateful if you can help or direct me to the best answer.

Thank you.

Dasal

Comment: Set your combobox object (how you set that is dependent on which combobox you are using). Then just before `If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then` statement, add the following line (presuming that your combobox object is called **oCB**): `oCB.Clear`. Remove the `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` clause from within your `For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount` loop (or comment it out) and replace it with `oCB.AddItem rs(i)`. That should do the trick

Comment: You could look at the  `.getrows` property of the recordset, and the `.list` property of the combo, I haven't time to test at the minute, but something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Object.List = r.GetRows`  Apologies for being vaque, I will revisit to see if can post full answer.

Comment: Thanks Zac. You've set me on the right path. With a bit of tweak, I was able to get the combobox populated,

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Selection()

Dim rs As Object

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim sqlstr As String
sqlstr = "Select * from Selection"

Call connectDatabase
rs.Open sqlstr, DBCONT

ComboBox1.Clear
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount

        ComboBox1.AddItem rs(1)
          rs.movenext
     Next i
 Else
    MsgBox "FFS"

 End If
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Call closeDatabase

 End Sub
```